# I can't import PhotoView.What should I do?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, implementation, android-photoview

I do not understand what to do with this plugin, I have been suffering for an hour .. My version is android studio 7.0.2
here is the code

````
 photoViewVersion = "2.3.0"
}
dependencies {
implementation "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:$photoViewVersion"
}```
````

Comment: What is the issue exactly  ? Does the gradle sync fails ? If it does what does it say ? Is there a red line or something ?  Elaborate more on the error .

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app.Other versions are also not displayed      it also writes: error: package com.github.chrisbanes.photoview does not exist
import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to your top level gradle build file.

See: https://github.com/Lichenwei-Dev/ImagePicker/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following in the build.gradle(Project level)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }   
}
```

Also try putting the dependency in the following manner in your gradle file (App level)

```
dependencies {
 def photoViewVersion = "2.3.0"
 implementation "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:$photoViewVersion"
}
```